# Query data to python from bigquery

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

**I'm trying to query data from bigquery to python and I have some problems. This is the main code :**

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas_gbq
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
{
[I can't write the details here but they are correct]
{
*******
})
project_id =******
df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq('SELECT user_pseudo_id FROM **** LIMIT 10',
                         project_id=project_id, credentials=credentials)
```

**After running the above code I get this message :**

Please visit this URL to authorize this application:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=495642085510-k0tmvj2m941jhre2nbqka17vqpjfddtd.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&state=ukIRV0Yf6wIrtYzClH76KnZhmt9c2I&prompt=consent&access_type=offline

**After that I continue the process of Google Accounts I get an authorization code.**

Enter the authorization code:

4/uQGt2eIGCepxYNfyBqXYaImFsdfsfyNhzsC8_UsPpYSYn_oRdynlC5H8

**And I after running the code I immediately get this output error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn

    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 57, in create_connection

    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo

    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen

    chunked=chunked)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request

    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn

    conn.connect()

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 301, in connect

    conn = self._new_conn()

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn

    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000072AF400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send

    timeout=timeout

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen

    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment

    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000072AF400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'))



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/udgtlvr/untitled4/bigquery", line 18, in <module>

    project_id=project_id, credentials=credentials)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 906, in read_gbq

    dialect=dialect, auth_local_webserver=auth_local_webserver)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 202, in __init__

    self.credentials = self.get_credentials()

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 216, in get_credentials

    credentials = self.get_user_account_credentials()

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 354, in get_user_account_credentials

    credentials = app_flow.run_console()

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 364, in run_console

    self.fetch_token(code=code)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 241, in fetch_token

    self.client_config['token_uri'], **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 221, in fetch_token

    verify=verify, proxies=proxies)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 581, in post

    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 360, in request

    headers=headers, data=data, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request

    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send

    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send

    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000072AF400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'))



Process finished with exit code 1


I have install so many libraries Related to this issue.
```

**What is the problem that causes such a long error?**

Comment: what's your Python version? And what Env are you using to run it on? I would try to review this and do some resetting of your configuration which I believe might help you solve your problem.

Comment: I'm on version 3.4 at anaconda enviorment.

Comment: I would suspect its the python version that's the cause of this.  Can you update to 3.5/3.6 or newer?  3.4 is currently EOL

Comment: sorry , I checked again and i'm on python 3.7 version

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue both inside my GCP project and outside to give you my conclusions.

After investigating I found that this error seems to be produced by overloading with requests the authorization page in a short period of time, as one of your last error messages suggest:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url...`

First, if you are using automated request, I would suggest to stop it while you narrow down the problem. Then make sure that you are using the correct client_id/secret.

After some time (I don't know the exact time interval), try with ONE request to verify your credentials.

Nonetheless, if you would like to retrieve data from BigQuery using Python, you can also use the official Client Libraries for BigQuery, where explains how to retrieve data in different programming languages, like Python, as stated [here.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries)

You could also use the [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas) which provides fast access to data stored in BigQuery.

Use the BigQuery Storage API to download data stored in BigQuery for use in analytics tools such as the pandas library for Python.

I hope this helps.